# Foundation .hide-for-small unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css, prototype, zurb-foundation

I am prototyping a few mockups for my site and have decided to use Foundation.  Foundation has a feature that easily allows you to hide page elements when the view port is less then 768px.  The strange thing is, then when I apply the .hide-for-small class to an element is shrinks the element by about 10px on all sideds.  It does not appear to be adding padding or margins, rather setting a new view port size only on that element.  this is most notice able when I apply the .hide-for-small class to elements with 100% widths.

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: https://github.com/timbo27/Foundation-Layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your code, but have some problem. You added 'columns' and 'hide-for-small' classes to wrapper div that is incorrect. You have to use 'columns' and 'hide-for-small' class in a 'row'.

For example your code have to be like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 hide-for-small columns">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 hide-for-small columns">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```